# Pause is not working in bat file after building angular and java

Tags: angular, windows, batch-file, cmd, build

I have this bat script that builds web app and java core. What I want is to build web app then core, but the bat file is closing after building web app. Here's my script

```
@echo off
echo building webapp.

pause
cd C:\dev\dashboard\dashboard-web
ng build --prod
pause

echo building core.

cd C:\dev\dashboard\dashboard-core
mvn clean package -DskipTests
pause
```

It close after build web app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `call` command to return execution to the parent script.

```
@echo off
echo building webapp.

pause
cd C:\dev\dashboard\dashboard-web
call ng build --prod
pause
```

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/call

Answer (score 1):

From the [Maven on Windows](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/windows-prerequisites.html) article: *You run Maven by invoking a command-line tool: `mvn.cmd`…*

Use

```
CALL mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

[Explanation](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html):

> ### CALL a second batch file
>
> The `CALL` command will launch a new batch file context along with any
>   specified parameters. When the end of the second batch file is reached
>   (or if *EXIT* is used), **control will return to just after the
>   initial `CALL` statement**.